# formula(s) to add "page breaks" to Google Sheets or x number of rows dynamically

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten

I have a sample GS [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rdBKQrJAk-FU-nhe2bph3LV6aDSH7hyLCZgx09NwaJQ/edit#gid=0).

I have a GS with multiple orders and each order has a different variety of items. An order might have 1 item or an order might have 200 items (rows).

I would like to figure out a way to print out each order on its own page and I'm wondering if there's a way to do this via formulas.

One example might be, I have 3 orders, each with 5-10 items so each order fits neatly on a page. I'd like to hit print once and have 3 pages print out, one for each order.

A more advanced example might be, I have 5 orders. 3 orders have few items so each order fits neatly on a page. But the other orders might have enough items to be multi-page orders. Again, I'd like to hit print once and have at least 5 pages print out.

Is there a way to do something like this? I started trying to do a query to count the number of lines each order has, and maybe do something with the Sequence function, but it quickly became out of my depths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX({input!A1:D1; TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(""&SPLIT(FLATTEN({
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(input!A2:A="",,"×"&input!A2:D&"9E+99")),,9^9)), 
 TEXT(IF(input!A2:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(input!A2:A&" "&
 COUNTIFS(input!A2:A, input!A2:A, ROW(input!A2:A), "<="&ROW(input!A2:A)), {input!A2:A&" "&
 COUNTIFS(input!A2:A, input!A2:A), IF(input!A2:A="",,
 REPT("9E+99 ", COLUMNS(input!A1:D1)))}, 2, 0))), SPLIT(REPT("@×", 
 4 + N("<< number of rows between")), 
 "×")), FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(input!A2:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(input!A2:A&" "&
 COUNTIFS(input!A2:A, input!A2:A, ROW(input!A2:A), "<="&ROW(input!A2:A)), {input!A2:A&" "&
 COUNTIFS(input!A2:A, input!A2:A), IF(input!A2:A="",,input!A1:D1&"9E+99")}, 
 SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(input!A:D))+1, 0)))),,9^9))}), "9E+99", 0), 
 "where Col3 is not null limit "&(COUNTUNIQUE(input!A2:A))*(
 4 + N("<< number of rows between"))+COUNTA(input!A2:A), 0), "×", ))})
```

[image]

for more or less rows in between change both `4`s

Comment: Wow. Works beautifully. Thank you!